# Identifing and authenticating an iPad (or tabled device) in a web app

Tags: javascript, ipad, authentication

I need to enforce my authentication mechanism from a simple username/password to username/password plus a unique identificator of the device that is connecting with the web app (eg: iPad or iPhone).

I've already read some posts that is not possibile in Javascript to have the UDID or MAC address of the device for security reason and this seems just for me, but I search for other unique identifier. Possibly I do not want to use applet or other stuff onto the device...

Is there any way to do this in Javascript, possibly onto iPad/iPhone?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is no.

You might be able to define one using a native application that is accessible from javascript. Such IDs don't provide any real security anyway, they are easily spoofed.

You don't know anything for certain about the user agents visiting your site, you can't trust anything that your script tells you about them. Nothing.

Comment: you are right. Adding an identifier doesn't improve the security of the auth mechanism. Spoofing the password is the same of spoofing the password plus the unique identifier. thanks a lot